# Wicked-Charts: This website contains interactive content

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, highcharts

My name is Luis and I am a web-developer.
I am using your Charts, but I am not being able to see them on Chrome and on Firefox, I have to unblock.

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Open the site in https
2. The chart doesn't appear

What is the expected output?
1. The chart to load when opening the site, without the need to "force" it to load.

What do you see instead?
Firefox:
1. Disable protection on this page 
2. The chart is loaded

Chrome:
1. Load unsafe script
2. The chart doesn't load

What version of the product are you using?
Wicket 6.x

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.wicked-charts</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicked-charts-wicket6</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

On what operating system?
Windows 7
Browser: Chrome: 34.0.1847.116 m and Firefox: 25
Charts source:    [Wicked-charts](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-charts/)

Thank you very much for your help,
Luis

Comment: Do you have any live demo ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
In your chart insert this code

public class TestChart extends Chart {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
    public TestChart(String id, Options options, Theme theme) {
        super(id, options, theme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onInitialize();
    String highcharts   = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";
    String exporting    = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js";
    JavaScriptResourceRegistry.getInstance().setHighchartsReference(highcharts);
    JavaScriptResourceRegistry.getInstance().setHighchartsExportingReference(exporting);
}
}
```

you need to set the urls for https